# How to build an IntersectionObserver in Composition API?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, jetbrains-ide, vue-composition-api

I am trying to implement an `IntersectionOberver` that will change the `url` when the viewport is moved into a new section. I found [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61645225/vue-router-change-anchor-in-route-on-scroll) and now trying to get it to work in `vue 3 compositon api`.

I'm trying to implement the script in my `index.vue` file, which is the parent of all other vue components:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <navbar></navbar>
    <social-media-bar></social-media-bar>
    <main>
      <home></home>
      <news></news>
      <vision></vision>
      <event-section></event-section>
      <artwork></artwork>
      <about></about>
      <donate></donate>
      <contact></contact>
      <partners></partners>
    </main>
    <footer-component></footer-component>
  </div>
</template>


<script setup>
import ... // component imports
import {onMounted, reactive} from "vue";
import router from "../js/router";

const state = reactive({
    sectionObserver: null
})

const sectionObserveHandler = (entries) => {
    for (const entry of entries) {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            router.push({name: 'news', hash: '#news'})
        }
    }
}
  
const observeSections = () => {
    const options = {
        rootMargin: '0px 0px',
        threshold: 0
    }
    state.sectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver(sectionObserveHandler, options)
    const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section')
    sections.forEach(section =>{
        state.sectionObserver.observe(section)
    })
}

onMounted(() => {
    observeSections()
})
</script>
```

Basically, what I want for now is to change the `url` to `.../#news` when the viewport is scrolled to the next `section`.

When I start the web app, it works without error messages, but no `url change` occurs upon scrolling down to sections.

What am I doing wrong?

What I've noticed is that Phpstorm is telling me at this line:

```
state.sectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver(sectionObserveHandler, options)
```

that:

```
Assigned expression type IntersectionObserver is not assignable to type UnwrapRef<null> ...   Type IntersectionObserver is not assignable to type null extends ShallowRef<infer V> ? V : (null extends Ref<infer V> ? UnwrapRefSimple<V> : UnwrapRefSimple<null>)     Type IntersectionObserver is not assignable to type null extends Ref<infer V> ? UnwrapRefSimple<V> : UnwrapRefSimple<null>
```

I've changed `state.sectionObserver` to `string`, `integer` or `array` but the error persists. Not sure if this is relevant to make this work though since browser seems to ignore it.

Comment: The question is specific to IDE and doesn't make sense in general. For some reason, Typescript checks are enabled in JS project. This may be specific to your config. Make sure TS isn't used in the project and there's no tsconfig.json in project root. Probably specific to how `script setup` is handled in IDE, try to change it to regular script. It could be fixed by doing `new IntersectionObserver` on `state` init because the instance itself doesn't depend on mount

Comment: @EstusFlask How would I create the `IntersectionObserver` on `state init`?

Comment: Likely `sectionObserver: new IntersectionObserver(...)`?

Comment: @EstusFlask but `IntersectionObserver` requires `sectionObserverHandler` and `options` which are created during the setup.

Comment: It's up to you where you create them. Nothing inside sectionObserverHandler and options determines that they should be created inside onMounted

Comment: Any way, the primary problem is IDE. You shouldn't have this error in the first place. The next time you'll have it you may have no alternative to fix it

Comment: @EstusFlask is the IDE comment even relevant to the problem? The browser ignores it.

Comment: That the problem exists in IDE but not when the app is built for browser means that it's IDE problem. This is Typescript error. It shouldn't appear if your project doesn't use TS. TS is mistakenly enabled in IDE for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out with the help of [This great tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8EYosX4NOo) by Kevin Powell.

Had to put this into my `index.vue`'s `script setup` tags:

```
onMounted(() => {
    const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section')
    const options = {
        threshold: 0.5
    }
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
            if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                console.log(entry.target)
            }
        })
    }, options)
    sections.forEach(section => {
        observer.observe(section)
    })
})
```